# Can't create trigger on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've already looked through other answers about triggers on phpmyadmin. One said to remove `BEGIN` and `END`, so I did. Many said to use a delimiter, which I also did. It still won't work.

The code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trig_EnderecoUpdated
ON tbdiref3_endereco AFTER UPDATE 
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF UPDATE(MORADOR_ID)
      INSERT INTO 
          tbdiref3_historico(END_ID, DATA, USUARIO_ID, MORADOR_ANTIGO)
          SELECT
             d.ID_END, GETDATE(), USER_NAME(), d.MORADOR_ID
          FROM 
             Deleted d
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I've also tried using backquotes on the table and column names. It always says the same thing, that I have a syntax error near `ON tbdiref3_endereco AFTER UPDATE FOR EACH ROW SET NOCOUNT ON IF UPDATE` on line 2. Any clues?

Comment: Set nocount is sql server is this tagged correctly?

Comment: @P.Salmon So I shouldn't use `set nocount on` in this case? I´m not using SQL server. I just put it in there because I read that one should always use it on triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was basing myself off of SQL Server examples which weren't compatible with MySQL. The following code ended up being accepted by PHPMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_EnderecoUpdated AFTER UPDATE ON tbdiref3_endereco FOR EACH ROW 
    IF NEW.MORADOR_ID != OLD.MORADOR_ID THEN 
        INSERT INTO tbdiref3_historico(END_ID, DATA, USUARIO_ID, MORADOR_ANTIGO) VALUES (OLD.ID_END, NOW(), CURRENT_USER(), OLD.MORADOR_ID); 
    END IF;
```